# Why am I getting many errors?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int getValueFromUser()
{
    std::cout << "Enter An Integer !";
    int valueTyped{};
    std::cin >> valueTyped;
    return valueTyped;
}
void double(int valueToBeMultiplied)
{
    getValueFromUser();
    std::cout << valueToBeMultiplied << "Doubled Is :" << valueToBeMultiplied * 2;
}
int main()
{
    double(getValueFromUser()); // Use the () double on the return value of the getValueFromUser()
    return 0;
}
```

```
invalid combination of type specifiers 10
expected an identifier 10
expected a '}' 12
this declaration has no storage class or type specifier 13
expected a ';' 13
expected a declaration 14

Error   C2556   'double getValueFromUser(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int getValueFromUser(void) 16
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2371   'getValueFromUser': redefinition; different basic types 16

Comment: `double` is a keyword in C++; you cannot use it as the name of a function.

Comment: oh thanks i totally forgot that !

Comment: You have a couple of other errors too. `getValueFromUser()` has an `int` return type, and `valueTyped` declared in `getValueFromUser()` is also an `int`. The parameter in your function `double_it` or whatever you choose to rename it to is also an `int`. So if you use an input like 4.5 you will lose the double precision if you don't change all of those types to `double`. Once you fix those you will also see that your value would be asked for twice before seeing an answer. I'll let you debug that to see if you can figure it out.

Comment: Yeah I removed the getValueFromUser() in the double_it function as it replicated the enter an integer output , thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem is that `double` is a keyword in C++. A `double` is a [fundamental type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) to represent a [double-precision floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) number. It cannot be used as the name of a function. Try renaming the function:

```
void double_it(int valueToBeMultiplied)
{
    getValueFromUser();
    std::cout << valueToBeMultiplied << "Doubled Is :" << valueToBeMultiplied * 2;
}
```